# React query: useInfiniteQuery only fetches the first page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I can't figure out why the `pageParam` is never increased by `PAGE_LIMIT` from the `getNextPageParam` function.
When I debug, `getNextPageParam` is correctly calculated but the value of `pageParam` in `fetchItems` stays at 0.

The first API call correctly returns the values for `next`, `offset` and `items`.

Can someone help? I want to retrieve all items from the API page by page until the `next` param is null.

```
export function useGetItems() {
    const PAGE_LIMIT = 50;
    const fetchItems = async ({ pageParam = 0 }) => {
 
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://...api.../items?limit=${PAGE_LIMIT}&offset=${pageParam}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ...`,
          },
        }
      );
  
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json();
        return {
          next: data.next,
          offset: data.offset,
          items: data.items as Item[],
        };
      } else {
        return { next: undefined, offset: pageParam, items: [] };
      }
    };
  
    const {
      data,
      error,
      fetchNextPage,
      hasNextPage,
      isFetching,
      isFetchingNextPage,
      refetch,
      status,
    } = useInfiniteQuery<
      { next: string; offset: number; items?: Item[] },
      Error
    >("items", fetchItems, {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, _pages) => {
        return lastPage.offset + PAGE_LIMIT;
      },
  
      enabled: false,
    });

    return { data, error, status, isFetching, refetch };

  }
```

Comment: I solved paging issue with '_pages.length + 1'

Comment: Thanks @botem. That wouldn't work in my case as the pagination of the api is linked to `offset` and not to the page number and I cannot change that (external 3rd party api)